# Intent.putExtra android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Столкнулся с очень простой проблемой, но не могу понять, почему не решается. Есть две Activity, при передаче из первой во вторую, id бъекта, во второй показывает 0. Хотя и id у объекта есть, и в смена deafultValue не выявило проблему.

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

    when(item?.itemId){

        R.id.add_note_item->{

            var addIntent=Intent(applicationContext,NoteActivity::class.java)

            var size=items.size

            addIntent.putExtra(NoteActivity.LIST_SIZE,size)

            Log.i("Items Size","${items.size}")
            startActivity(addIntent)
            return true
        }

        R.id.delete_all_menu->{
            dbHandler.deleteDB()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

NoteActivity.kt

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

    when (item?.itemId) {
        R.id.add_item_menu -> {

            var intent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)

            var size = intent.getIntExtra(LIST_SIZE, 0)

            var id = intent.getIntExtra(ID_TEXT, 0)

            var status=intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_STATUS,false)


            Log.i("ID NoteActivity", id.toString())
            Log.i("SIZE NoteActivity", size.toString())

            if(status){
                var dbHandler = DBHelper(this, null)
                note = Note(
                    id, noteActivityName.text.toString(),
                    noteActivityText.text.toString(),
                    noteActivityDate.text.toString()
                )
                dbHandler.updateNote(note)
            }
            if(id==0) {
                var dbHandler = DBHelper(this, null)
                note = Note(
                    size+1, noteActivityName.text.toString(),
                    noteActivityText.text.toString(),
                    noteActivityDate.text.toString()
                )
                dbHandler.addNote(note)

            }
```

Переменная size в MainActivity равна размеру листа, а в NoteActivity, как то не хочет.

Метод onCreate в NoteActivity

```
 lateinit var note: Note

var random:Random=Random()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.note_activity)

    val date = getCurrentDateTime()
    val dateInString = date.toString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")

    var id = intent.getIntExtra(ID_TEXT, 0)


    var status=intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_STATUS,false)


    if(status){
        showNoteDB(id)
        noteActivityName.setText(note.name)
        noteActivityText.setText(note.text)
    }
    noteActivityDate.text = dateInString


}
```

В нём переменая id достаётся из MainActivity, а в onOptionItemSelected, не хочет вылазить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в этой строке:

```
var intent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
```

здесь вы создаёте новый интент и в нём, естественно, нет никаких данных.
Так же эта локальная переменная с пустым интентом перекрывает одноимённое свойство `intent`, в котором хранится тот интент, с которым была запущена активность.

Достаточно убрать эту строку и вы получите свои данные через это свойство.